# What is the difference between 'curricula' and 'curriculum'?

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference between 'curricula' and 'curriculum'? Both appear to have the same definition. Are they used in the same context?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Curricula* is the plural of *curriculum*.

Answer (score 6):

*Curriculum* is a collection of subjects taught and is a singular noun. Its plural form is *curricula* or *curriculums*.

For example, we can say

> The two schools have different
>   curricula.

Similarly, the plural of *referendum* is *referenda* or *referendums*.

Answer (score 6):

Curricula is the plural of curriculum.

This question, asked in a more general way, might be, "What is a common way of forming plural vs. singular for Latin-derived words?" There is a whole list of them and they come in multiple patterns:

- curriculum vs. curricula
- referendum vs. referenda
- datum vs. data
- medium vs. media
- focus vs. foci

There are certainly more, but these come to mind.